# Google Map geolocation keep on going to the centre during dragging or clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, geolocation

I am confused with why the map will get centered (to my current position) when I drag. I am not sure with what happen but I think it is because it loops through my getLocation when I drag/click. Here is my code

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Class Project</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(MY_API_KEY)"></script>

    <div id="map" onclick= "initMap()">Get your Location</div>


</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
function initMap() {                                                                    //#1

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, errorHandler);
}

function errorHandler(err) {
            if(err.code == 1) {
               alert("Access to your location denied, refresh page.");
            }

            else if( err.code == 2) {
               alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
            }
         }

function getLocation(position){
        var msg = {
        info: '<strong>Madison Square Garden</strong><br>\
                    4 Pennsylvania Plaza<br> New York, NY 10001, USA<br>\
                    <a href="https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Madison+Square+Garden/@40.7505045,-73.9934387,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x33df10e49762f8e4!8m2!3d40.7505045!4d-73.9934387?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNpdHKyN3TAhVJk5QKHdvOCTEQ_BIIjgEwDA">Get Directions</a>',
        lat: 40.7505045,
        long: -73.9934387
    };


    var locations = [
      [msg.info, msg.lat, msg.long, 0],
    ];

    var latitude = position.coords.latitude,
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of `onclick= "initMap()"` in the map rendering div.

Problem is because you load map with `onclick` . If  drag the map , `onclick` event is triggered and map is again loaded .

You should use `window.onload=initMap()`  to load map or have button to load map `onclick` as shown below.

It should be

```
<button onclick= "initMap()">
Load Map
</button>
<div id="map" >Get your Location</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xeduj0ft/) demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible to get rid of the button upon clicking?

Comment: yes you can remove button. And you can see in script  src url there is  `&callback=initMap` .it is enough to call map on load